# Center paragraph while having margins to create empty spaces

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, paragraph

So I am trying to center my paragraph in the middle of the page while creating some left and right margin **"empty spaces".**

My goal is to put it in a text-box like style and have it center of the page while creating empty columns on the left and right hand side of the page. I like what I have in desktop mode but it is *"stationary"* and not responsive. When you resize your browser in responsive mode, it does not stay center. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve as shown in my quick sketch below and my codes.

**GOAL:** Also when I resize my browser to mobile, I want that "*text-box*" to start **filling** the margins so that it looks readable when you're on your phone or tablet. **BONUS:** I want to change the width or margin size for either side of the text-box to make it look good and evenly along with my other contents that I have in my full html document. This is just a part of my html document.

***NOTE:*** When you run the code snippet, I suggest you click onto *Full Page* so that you can see what I'm talking about to make it easier to follow along.

[image]

```css
.mainSummary {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-right: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div class="mainSummary">
  <p style="background-color: lightblue; border: 2px solid lightgreen; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 22px;">
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `max-width: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` using fixed margin will directly effect on responsive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex + auto margins may help to achieve your goal.

**Working example**: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/LqyaZx

```css
.summary {
    display: flex;
}

.summary__content {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: lightblue; 
    border: 2px solid lightgreen; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 22px;
    /* Set the desired max-width for mobile */
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="summary">
    <p class="summary__content">
      At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis 
      praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas 
      molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique 
      sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks! Can you kindly explain to me what does margin: 0 and auto does? Just want to know what each of the function serve.

Comment: And I'm confuse with what in the padding that says 1rem what dooes that mean? And which property do I use to change the width on each side of my box?

Comment: @azazel, well the `0` means no margin at all at the top and bottom. On the other hand, the `margin: auto` in flex works very similarly to auto margins in block flow (any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension). You can read the full details in the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: `rem` is a unit. Check it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: And which one do I use to change the size of my box? (width)

Comment: I think a better question would be "Which property do I use to stretch or shrink the box?"

Comment: I used `max-width` in the example, but you can use `width` + `media queries`, based on your mobile devices support.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help! This is just exactly what I needed to achieve my envision goal! Best way I usually learn is to sometimes play around with the different properties and see what they do.

Comment: @Azazel you don't need flexbox at all .. the answer is somehow missleading because you will think that the answer is the flexbox but the answer is simply "add a max-width". Remove `display:flex` and it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.mainSummary {
    margin-left: 100%;
    margin-right: 100%;
}
```

Or

```
.mainSummary {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. If you don't have Bootstrap 4 then flex won't work. So without flex, you can try this.

```
.mainSummary {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```